# Way to use previous data with current data in pyspark with kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am sending dict objects from my producer and using pyspark to create a new object. But the kind of obj I want to form requires the key, value pair of previous data also. I tried window batching and reduceByKey but none of them seems to work.

Suppose my producer object is like a list of "url_id" and "url" pair. For ex.{"url_id": "google.com"} and in spark i want to form an object like: {"data": {"url_id": "url", "url_id_of_previous_url": "url",....and so on}

My spark code is:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[*]")
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

        stream_context = StreamingContext(sparkContext=sc, batchDuration=batchTime)
        kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc=stream_context, topics=[topic], 
                                          kafkaParams={"metadata.broker.list":"localhost:9092", 
                                                     'auto.offset.reset':'smallest'})
        lines = kafka_stream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))
```

I am stuck after this. Can u tell me if forming such obj is possible or not with spark? And if it is then what should I use?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can solve this in 2 ways,

**First approach** will be simple to let the message producing application itself to send the pair of messages (current & previous) by enabling some internal caching into it.

**Second approach** is to use Spark Stateful Streaming to maintain the last message's values in Spark state context. As you are using PySpark, the only option which I know is to use the `updateStateByKey` with check point enabled.

The typical flow will be as follows with PySpark Streaming,

- To define initial value and update function
- maintain a common key to match the current and previous messages, I used `pair_msgs` in this example.

  ```
  # RDD with initial state (key, value) pairs
  initialStateRDD = sc.parallelize([(u'pair_msgs', '{"url_id":"none"}')])

  def updateFunc(new_url_msg, last_url_msg):
      if not new_url_msg:
          return last_url_msg
      else:
          new_url_dict = json.loads(new_url_msg[0])
          new_url_dict['url_id_previous'] = json.loads(last_url_msg)['url_id']
          return json.dumps(new_url_msg)
  ```
- To map the input messages with the common key, `pair_msgs` in this example.
- invoke `updateStateByKey` transformation with the above update function.

  ```
  feeds = kafka_stream.map(lambda x: x[1])

  pair_feed = feeds.map(lambda feed_str: ('pair_msgs', feed_str)) \
               .updateStateByKey(updateFunc, initialRDD=initialStateRDD)
  ```

*[Note: As for as I know, PySpark Structured Streaming is yet to get Stateful Streaming support, So I believe the above example still makes sense]*